# Is `Symmetric operator linear`

Tags: functional-analysis

Today reading a book functional analysis of this sentence stroke. please could you help someone to prove this means i.e. that: **symmetric operator is linear**, thank you preliminarily. Thanky very much

Definiton of the symmetric operator: Let be $X$ a unitary space. Operator $A:X\rightarrow X$ is *symmetric* if
$$(Ax\vert y)=(x\vert Ay)$$ $$(x,y\in X)$$

Comment: What is a symmetric operator?

Comment: $(A(x_1 + x_2) | y) = (x_1 + x_2, Ay) = (Ax_1, y) + (Ax_2,y)$. If this holds for every $y$, then...

Comment: please help me, to prove this fact

Comment: Consider what it means to be linear, and look at what I've written as a hint.

Comment: please help me because I did not understand very well these definitions, so I applied this site, believing that someone will help me

Comment: In that case, I think you should probably review concepts involving linearity and linear algebra before you dive into functional analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume the "mathematician's" convention that the inner product is linear in the first variable and conjugate-linear in the second.  For vectors $x$, $y$, $z$ and scalar $t$,

$$\eqalign{\langle A(x+ty) | z \rangle  &= \langle (x+ty) | A z \rangle\cr & = \langle x | A z \rangle + t \langle y | A z \rangle\cr
& = \langle Ax | z \rangle + t \langle A y | z \rangle\cr
&= \langle Ax + tAy | z \rangle }$$

Since this is true for all $z$, $A(x+ty) = Ax + tAy$.